# How to develop people count of office?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I would like to count how many persons are in 1) conference room and 2) Office for 100 persons. I would like to have bar graph for room or office occupancy.

I learned from vendor like Viametrics that camera like thermal camera must be installed to roof outside of conference room to count in and out of traffic. It seem regular camera can be used or some kind of mats as well.

I tried Azure Cognitive Emotion API for people counting, but it is reliable only if camera sees whole face. Result of experiment was that we cannot use Emotion API.

I would like to know that if I had camera and RaspBerry(or Arduino) plus Azure or Bluemix or VM, how to build people counting solution. Do you know any library or API?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a cognitive service like that. I think you'll have to develop your own service.

This is the way I would go about this:

1. Train or fine-tune Fast-RCNN or Yolo model to identify a person on a photo. See examples [here](https://softwaremill.com/counting-objects-with-faster-rcnn/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Object-Detection-using-Fast-R-CNN).
2. Then put a simple script on top that will count number of identified objects.
3. Create a docker container that will contain simple server. That server would listen to particular camera / or set of cameras and score your model.
4. Use Azure Container Service / Kubernetes to put your containers in Azure, and also to create scaleable service.